# jQuery UI Dialog Div not working with hidden Class - only with style="display none"

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

hi my team has the convention not to use inline style "display none"
so i tried to apply a hidden class to my jquery ui dialogues, which is not working. does anyone have experience with this?

```
{% for event in swRegional %}
                 <div class="dialog" data-index="loop7{{ loop.index0 }}">
                    <li class="contentli">{{ event.value }} {{ event.subline }}</li>
                 </div>
                <div style="display:none;" id="anmelden_boxloop7{{ loop.index0 }}" class="{{ event.value }}{{ loop.index0 }}" >
                    {% include 'ansprechpartnerSingle.twig' %}
                        {% if loop.index0 == 0 %}
                             {% for key, ap in ansprechpartner %}
                            <li class="ansprechpartnerContainer ceo0">{{ ap.swRegional0 }}</li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                        {% if loop.index0 == 1 %}
                             {% for key, ap in ansprechpartner %}
                            <li class="ansprechpartnerContainer ceo0">{{ ap.swRegional1 }}</li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                </div>  
            {% endfor %}
```

this is the current code, when i add class hidden with { display:none } the dialog shows nothing.

like everytime, feel free to downvote  :-)

Comment: Oh! God. You must be so tortured from all that down-voting!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="anmelden_boxloop7{{ loop.index0 }}" class="{{ event.value }}{{ loop.index0 }} hidden" >
```

I think this should do.

Comment: then the dialogue is empty, but nevertheless you get +1 for participating

Comment: What do you mean it is empty? Are you trying to say that the contents inside the dialog is cleared?